# Observer not called and postvalue not working from background thread when activity is destroyed then recreated

Tags: java, android, mvvm

The following simple example code have an asynchronous task that repeatedly sleeps for 2 seconds then trigger a callback function `onResultAvailable` with `"some text .."` (which I use here to simulate a websocket thread that receives messages ...).

The `onResultAvailable` method in the `MyViewModel` class is supposed to update the variable `text` (which is a `MutableLiveData<String>`) using `postValue` (because it is called from a background thread).

So this code is supposed to update the `text` variable each two seconds and display the text via the observer in `MyTestActivity`; so it is supposed to display the following, which works as expected the first time:

```
Some text 0
Some text 1
Some text 2
... etc
```

However, when I press the backbutton and then open `MyTestActivity` again, the `text` variable isn't modified anymore by `postvalue` and the observer isn't called anymore. Note that the other variables which are modified using `setvalue` are still behaving as expected.

Any ideas why the `postvalue` works fine from background thread the first time, but doesn't work anymore when the activity is destroyed then recreated ? How, can I update the value of the `text` variable in this case ?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.myButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyTestActivity.class));
        });
    }
}
```

**MyTestActivity.java**

```
public class MyTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView myTextView, myTextViewTime;
    Button myButton;
    MyViewModel vm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_test);
        myTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        myTextViewTime = findViewById(R.id.myTextViewTime);
        myButton = findViewById(R.id.myButton);

        vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

        vm.getText().observe(this, text -> {
            myTextView.setText(text);
            Log.d("DEBUG", "observed: " + text);
        });

        vm.getTimestamp().observe(this, strTs -> {
            myTextViewTime.setText(strTs);
            Log.d("DEBUG", "observed: " + strTs);
        });

        myButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            vm.setTimestamp("" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        });
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.java**

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel implements MyAsyncTaskDelegate {
    private MutableLiveData<String> text;
    private MutableLiveData<String> timestamp;
    private MyAsyncTask task;

    public MyViewModel() {
        text = new MutableLiveData<>();
        text.setValue("Hello World!");

        timestamp =  new MutableLiveData<>();
        timestamp.setValue(""+System.currentTimeMillis());

        task = new MyAsyncTask(this);
        task.execute();
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public LiveData<String> getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String ts) {
        timestamp.setValue(ts);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResultAvailable(String result) {
        text.postValue(result);
    }
}
```

**MyAsyncTask.java**

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private MyAsyncTaskDelegate delegate;

    MyAsyncTask(MyAsyncTaskDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                delegate.onResultAvailable("Some text " + i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MyAsyncTaskDelegate.java**

```
public interface MyAsyncTaskDelegate {
    void onResultAvailable(String result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas why the postvalue works fine from background thread the first time, but doesn't work anymore when the activity is destroyed then recreated ?

In a nutshell: this happens because `MyAsyncTask.doInBackground()` will loop infinitely and for most Android versions, there is no parallel execution of `AsyncTask`s.

In `MyTestActivity.onCreate()`, you generate a new instance of `MyViewModel` which starts its own `MyAsyncTask`. Because the first instance of `MyAsyncTask` never finishes, the second one never really starts. The first instance of `MyAsyncTask` still holds on to the first instance of `MyViewModel` (aka `MyAsyncTaskDelegate`). But since this first `MyViewModel` instance does not have any connection to an active UI element, the updates don't show on the screen.

You can verify this with a debugger by setting breakpoints in the various methods and comparing the "instance numbers" (there is a '@' and a unique number appended to each class name)

Please note that the problematic behavior only happens if you leave `MyTestActivity` by pressing BACK. If you rotate the device, the updates continue.

This is "working as intended". By pressing BACK, you indicate that you don't need the current instance of `MyTestActivity` anymore: it won't be kept on the back stack, it can and will be completely destroyed.

The `AsyncTask` is another case: it is a member of `MyViewModel` and on the other hand holds a reference to `MyViewModel`. One could say there is a reference deadlock: it will only be stopped if the whole surrounding pocess is stopped.

> How can I update the value of the text variable in this case ?

Override `onBackPressed()` in `MyTestActivity` and stop the execution of `MyAsyncTask`. See the docs on [AsyncTask.cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#cancel(boolean)) on how to do so.